# Magento 2: How to add array of input fields in admin panel?

Tags: magento2, admin, custom-field, fieldsets, addfield

I wanna display an array of input fields in Cart Prices Rules page under Condition's tab like this:

[image]

I have a [similar example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198654/magento2-store-configuration-table-with-multiple-fields) which does this in stores/configuration section but I wanna achieve this in magento Rules somewhere under Conditions section:

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Found any solutions on this topic?