# Magento 2 Image upload in table view to store configuration page

Tags: magento2

We want to add the "Image Upload" option to table view type multiple fields under store configuration section using system.xml. Check the below screenshot for more clarification.

[image]

Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in your System.xml file its work**

[image]

```
<field id="logo" translate="label" type="image" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Image Upload</label>
            <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
            <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">logo</upload_dir>
            <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">logo</base_url>
            <comment><![CDATA[Allowed file types: jpeg, gif, png.]]></comment>
        </field>
```

**Thanks**

Comment: As i told before i want this in table type view. In Magento language in serialization fields. Do not want sign image upload fields but want it with other 2 fields. Check screenshot shared by me.

Comment: Try this, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198654/magento2-store-configuration-table-with-multiple-fields